# PHP form submit not working on specific machine

Tags: php, forms

I am working our backend system, there is a `form` which is submitted through `HTML submit button` via `POST` Method. On server side form is validated through `Zend form` and data stored in `mysql` and page redirected to data listing page.
This flow is working fine with all systems except for a particular machine (windows machine any browser) where `form` won't get submitted properly, its `data` got corrupted, few fields as missing.
All other functionalities (including form submit) are working fine on same machine, except this form.

Code phtml (form)

```
<form name='frm_main' id='frm_main' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php  echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="post" >
<?php $this->form->layerhtml->setAttrib('cols','85'); echo $this->form->layerhtml ;?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="green_btn">
</form>
```

controller (server side)

```
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    // processing 
}
```

Comment: just try to see if it is a problem of URL or some other path used in your form.

Comment: @Robin there is no problem in url, also note that I am using post method for submitting data

Comment: it would be better if we get to see the code

Comment: Can you give us the complete form in html after the php function calls have been made and the screen is rendered

Comment: @LarryLane complete form is very large and also sort of confidential, so I can't post code for that.
I have considered checking `form tags` for any mismatch, but there all seems perfect for me